# How to Compare two worksheets' columns, highlight the same values #code

Tags: excel, vba

I am a newbie here, also a newbie in VBA.

I have two worksheets that I wanted to compare.

Let's say,

- Sheet1

  - Column DWG. NO
  - Column SYM
- Sheet2

  - Column DWG. NO
  - Column SYM

But the column position of DWG and SYM in sheet2 is not always the same so first I need to locate the positions of the column before comparing. Then highlight the comparison.

Take note also that the sheets have thousands of row data and multiple columns. But only two columns are needed to be compared.

This is the working code:

```
Sub LookForMatches()
    Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range, c1 As Range, c2 As Range
    Dim rng3 As Range, rng4 As Range, c3 As Range, c4 As Range
'set ranges
    Set rng1 = Sheets("datax").Range("C5", Sheets("datax").Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    Set rng2 = Sheets("datay").Range("AC4", Sheets("datay").Range("AC" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    Set rng3 = Sheets("datax").Range("F5", Sheets("datax").Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    Set rng4 = Sheets("datay").Range("AH4", Sheets("datay").Range("AH" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))

'reset colour
    rng1.Interior.Color = 16777215
    rng2.Interior.Color = 16777215
    rng3.Interior.Color = 16777215
    rng4.Interior.Color = 16777215
'loop values in range
    For Each c1 In rng1
        If Not c1.Interior.ColorIndex = 16777215 And c1 <> "" And c1 <> 0 Then
            For Each c2 In rng2
                If c1 = c2 And c2.Address <> c1.Address Then
                    c1.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
                    c2.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
                End If
            Next c2
        End If
    Next c1
'loop values in next range
    For Each c3 In rng3
        If Not c3.Interior.ColorIndex = 16777215 And c3 <> "" And c3 <> 0 Then
            For Each c4 In rng4
                If c3 = c4 And c4.Address <> c3.Address Then
                    c3.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
                    c4.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
                End If
            Next c4
        End If
    Next c3
    MsgBox ("Checking Done")
    Application.Goto Sheets("datay").Range("AA1"), True
End Sub
```

But sheet2's column location is defined. 
However, it should not be defined based on the column number but on the header name because the position of column is varying.

Thank you so much.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please don't upload a file, just copy/paste your code into the question, select it and press Ctrl+K to format it as code block. We can only help you if we see what you have tried so far. Otherwise this is to broad to answer (see [ask]). Please also note that *"is not working*" is no useful error description. Instead explain which errors you get or where exactly you got stuck. Explain what your code does vs what you expect it to do. Reading [mcve] might help too to improve your question (you didn't ask one yet).

Comment: In which line do you get the error and what is the exact error message?

Comment: Only error 1004 pops up.

Comment: Actually, the code is totally not working. It doesn't highlight the columns.

Comment: And because the PC is in Japanese the error pops up like "????? 1004: ???????". Thanks for entertaining my question.

Comment: In which line of the code does the error occur? Go through your code step by step using F8.

Comment: Error occurs at Set i = Range("DWG. NO").Find("*", Range("DWG. NO")(1), , , xlPrevious)

Comment: Looking at `Range("DWG. NO")`, is "DWG. NO" a named range (e.g. created via Formulas > Define Name) or is it just the column header? If it's only a column header then it won't be recognised as an argument to Range

Comment: Yes it is a column header. Is it not possible to use column name to find the column data? Because the column position of the data is not always fix. I need to first search for the DWG. NO column then compare.

Comment: Hi, I change the ranges to this: 
    Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range, c1 As Range, c2 As Range
    Dim rng3 As Range, rng4 As Range, c3 As Range, c4 As Range
    Dim col1 As String, col2 As String
    
'define column
    col1 = "DWG. NO"
    col2 = "SYM."
    
'set ranges
    Set rng2 = Sheets("datay").Cells.Find(what:=col1, lookat:=xlWhole)
    Set rng4 = Sheets("datay").Cells.Find(what:=col2, lookat:=xlWhole)

But during loop it doesn't highlight anything.
What is lacking with this code?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you are doing this using VBA: I created two columns, A:A and B:B, and I used conditional formatting to colour cells, based on their presency in column A:A, based on this formula:

```
=IFNA(MATCH(B2;$A$2:$A$4;0);FALSE)      // for colouring if found
=NOT(IFNA(MATCH(B2;$A$2:$A$4;0);FALSE)) // for colouring otherwise if not found
```

Comment: Because sheet2 is varying. The image is this. In a workbook, there is a front page, then sheet1 and sheet2. Sheet1(datax) has a pile of data (fix data) then using macro, i will insert sheet2(datay). After comparing and highlighting the target column, I need to move the sheet2(datay) and save as .xlsx. after that a new sheet2(dataz) will be inserted and compared to sheet1(datax). This will be a continuous comparing of new data in reference to sheet1(datax). That's why VBA is necessary. To lessen the copy/paste of excel formula in a sheet. I think.

Comment: But thank you for answering the question. I appreciate it a lot. Thanks